# Are "speaking of" and "regarding" equivalent?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

The interviewer asks "What do you like about your job?"

Is it correct to answer:

> "**Speaking of** the things I like the most about my job. First,… Second …"

Or

> "**Regarding** the things I like the most about my job. First,… Second…"

Comment: It would be quite awkward to answer a question with either of those preambles. Surely in any language. But "regarding" is slightly better. "Speaking of" here would actually mean: "Here's a related idea that you didn't directly mention but that I think is connected with our current topic." ("I like all kinds of animals." - "Speaking of animals, have you taken your kids to the zoo yet?")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"speaking of" x implies the idea has already been mentioned by either speaker. Also, it is used when actually speaking.

*regarding* means "on the subject of x" or "about" and is often used in writing though it *can be used* in more formal speech.

"I spoke to the human resources department regarding the incident", he said to his boss.

"There was no further information *regarding his whereabouts*." [a police report, for example].

So, yes, they mean the same thing but are used quite differently.